# Хранение файлов пользователя

Tags: база-данных, изображения, хранение-данных

На сайте пользователи могут загружать свои изображения в любых количествах (свои фотоальбомы). Файлы храню пока локально вида /files/u1/sdF/aXnKDpt2eg.jpg .

C местом для хранения разобрался, а вот как в базе всё это хранить не знаю. Сначала думал сделать таблицу files с полями id, path и привязывать по id, но подозреваю, что эта таблица быстро распухнет до нескольких миллионов и работать будет медленнее.

Так вот интересует, как лучше хранить ссылки на изображения в базе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А какая именно работа с базой предполагается? Если добавить уникальное поле с user-id и проиндексировать его, то выборка из миллиона записей займет доли секунды.
Какая нагрузка на проект?

**Обновление**

Пользователей же конечное число, верно? User-id - это id конкретного пользователя, уникальный для таблицы пользователей. Добавь еще одно поле в таблицу с фото, где указывай какому пользователю принадлежит фото. Проиндексируй этот столбец, тогда при поиске фотки для  конкретного пользователя выборка будет осуществляться не из миллиона записей, а только из тех, которые принадлежат кокретному пользователю. Все это будет работать очень быстро, если запрос на выборку в правильном порядке составить.

Аватарки с альбомами и фотографиями лучше не мешать, т.к. эти данные выводятся с разной частотой.

Comment: уникальное не получится, ведь у одного пользователя могут быть сотни фотографий. Фотографии физически не удаляются, даже если пользователь удаляет, просто ставится флаг deleted. Уникальный будет только id - инкремент.
Хотел создать таблицу с файлами, которая ни чего не хранит кроме id и пути к файлу (ну м.б. дату добавления ещё), и все все фотки (аватарки, альбомы и просто фотки) сливать туда, но сейчас понимаю, что так, наверное, не получится.

Comment: @Get, да, в этом есть смысл. наверное, так и поступлю. хотя изначально, конечно, не хотелось в таблице держать связи с другими таблицами.

Comment: Какой смысл использовать реляционную БД (например MySQL), если не делать связей между таблицами? Без связей, индексации и использования отработанных и скомпилированных методов поиска, лежащих в основе БД будет действительно тяжело и работать медленно.

Comment: @Get, я не хотел держать связь в этой таблицы, только из других. например, чтобы аноним тоже мог что-то загрузить. хотя пример, мб не совсем удачный, но идея в том, чтобы хранить ссылки на запись в других таблицах, например, `user`.`avatar` или `albom`.`cover`. При сама запись не знает ничего о том, откуда она и где/кем загружена и используется.